# binary search tree postorder traversal by iteration

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

i implemented an iterative post-order algorithm along with pre and inorder . but the iterative post-order is not working.all my efforts are in vain to spot the bug.
the program crashes before printing the last node data of tree in post-order.

this is the code snippet.

```
t=root;

    while(t!=NULL || !st.empty())
    {
        if(t!=NULL)
        {
            if(t->r!=NULL)
                st.push(t->r);
            st.push(t);
            t=t->l;
        }
        else
        {
            t=st.top();
            st.pop();
            if(t->r!=NULL && t->r==st.top())
            {
                st.pop();
                st.push(t);
                t=t->r;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<t->data<<" ";
                t=NULL;
            }
        }
    }
```

more info: st is STL stack and consider root as global(in my code, above snippet is a part of a class and so is root variable )

Comment: clean up your code and show the relevant parts

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth is it ok now or should i completely delete the part that shows no error.

Comment: remove everything that's irrelevant, I see some preorder and inorder stuff there, make it go away, delete, remove, eradicate, garfunkle, what have you, show the code that causes the error and / or potentially some immediate call stack candidates if you're not entirely sure about where or why the error happens

Comment: Are you sure that the postorder traversal is being performed properly here? It looks like this algorithm does not properly support handling of the right side of the tree.

Comment: @WLin no, i checked it with recursive post-order for a large number of inputs. it is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
if(t->r!=NULL && t->r==st.top())
```

the issue is that the stack may be empty at this point, in which case calling st.top() will cause the program to crash.

You can fix this by changing the line to:

```
if(t->r!=NULL && !st.empty() && t->r==st.top())
```

### Example

If your tree has root connected to NULL on its left, and A on its right then the program will:

1. push A (stack now has A)
2. push root (stack now has A,root)
3. pop root (stack now has A)
4. pop A (stack is now empty)
5. push root (stack now has root)
6. push A (stack has root,A)
7. pop A and print A's data (stack has root)
8. pop root (stack is now empty)
9. At this stage the program has an empty stack and t->r!=NULL so it will access st.top

Comment: can you think of any other error because i tried a lot of time to prove myself that the stack won't be empty.

Comment: more info:initially the stack is empty.

Comment: By the way, does the change fix your program when you run it?